# Get value of return variable after subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular

I doing an Async call using the below code, I want to know the value of `data` that is generated inside the `getData()` function however, I am getting `undefined` because the call is not resolved yet. Is there any way to sort it out?

```
getData(address){
let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&key='+this.key;  
let call = this.http.get(url).subscribe(data =>{

  let data = data.json()
  return data;

});
}

//this is undefined because it does not know if the call was finished or not
console.log(this.latlong)

secondMethod(item){
    //this is also undefined
    this.getData(item.address)
}
```

Comment: Put a `console.log(data)` inside the `subscribe()`.

Comment: inside `subscribe` it prints the data, the issue is outside `suscribe`

Comment: As you already said, *"I doing an Async call..."*, so you can't assume that the request is resolved outside the `subscribe`. The statements outside are *generally* executed before.. Btw, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, look at asynchronous code with typescript as it can make it more readable

Comment: @developer033 there should be a way to get that value for sure, I need to get the latitude and longitude from Google Maps API generated inside `getData()` and get the `data` inside `secondMethod()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is what you can do to solve it, simply push the data inside an array, then you may retrieve it in other functions.

```
getData(address){

let array = [];

 let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?    address='+address+'&key='+this.key;  
 let call = this.http.get(url).subscribe(data =>{

let data = data.json()
array.push(data);

});
 return array;
 }


 secondMethod(item){
//now you'll be able to retrieve it !
this.getData(item.address)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getData(address){
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&key='+this.key;  
    return this.http.get(url).map(data => data.json());
})
```

Then you need to subscribe to get a value.

```
secondMethod(item){
    this.getData(item.address).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` inside second method prints `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could make that work keeping in mind async.

```
getData(address, callback){
  let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
  address='+address+'&key='+this.key;  
  let call = this.http.get(url).subscribe(callback);
}

secondMethod(item){
    this.getData(item.address, this.thirdMethod.bind(this))
}

thirdMethod(data) {
  let data = data.json()
  // do stuff
  this.something = data['something'];
}
```

Comment: It's the concept of how to do async that this illustrates - if there's a minor syntax error I expect you to find and fix it or at least report the error message, and this code working is dependent on the rest of your code working.